# Como faço para construir atributos baseados em valores definidos no método __init__ na minha classe?

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos

Eu escrevi a seguinte classe:

```
class Words():
    def __init__(self, value, g_class, first_meaning = True):
        self.value = value
        self.g_class = g_class
        self.first_meaning = first_meaning
    #attribute meaning
    meaning = ''
    #is the word in my local dictionary?
    if self.value in brecht_dict.keys():
            self.meaning = brecht_dict[self.value]
```

Os argumentos `value`, `g_class` e `first_meaing` são, respectivamente, a string que corresponde à palavra, sua classe gramatical e se o usuário quer todos as entradas do dicionário referente aquela palavra ou apenas a primeira. Essa parte do código roda normalmente.

Contudo, gostaria de criar um atributo chamado `meaning` que retorna o significado da palavra. O que tentei fazer foi criar `meaning` como uma string vazia primeiro e depois verificar se tenho ela em um dicionário interno. Ocorre quando faço isso o programa retorna o seguinte erro:

```
name 'self' is not defined
```

Para mim está claro que `self` só existe dentro do método, mas como faço para chamar o valor de `value` fora do método?

Comment: olhe a identação, o if esta fora do metodo, ele esta no escopo global, arrume a identação para dentro do metodo __init__, ou crie outro metodo

Comment: Eu sei. Quero criar um atributo fora do método mesmo. `meaning` não seria um atributo em um método particular, apenas da classe. Isso é possível, né?

Comment: eu conseguiria usar self.value dentro de outro método?

Comment: @Hartnäcking só para conseguir te dar uma resposta, você quer que o ```meaning``` seja um atributo depois de inicializar um objeto com o ```__init__ ```certo ?

Comment: sim. Pq `meaning` vai precisar de algumas informações presentes na inicialização do objeto

Comment: basta não usar self, porem vc tem que ficar atento para a inicialização do mesmo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primeiro de tudo, esse erro aí ocorre porque durante a definição da sua classe, ainda não há um objeto, logo não há um `self`. E por esse motivo, não é possível você verificar se você tem o valor desejado no dicionário fora de um método.

Além disso, o código da verificação já será executado ao definir a classe, como você pode ver nesse simples exemplo que eu fiz:

```
class App():

    with open("settings.txt") as settings:

        if settings.read() == "pt-br":
            msg = "Olá! Como você está ?"
        else:
            msg = "Hello! How are you ?"

    def hello(self):
        print(self.msg)
```

Nesse exemplo o código fora do método é executado antes mesmo de eu criar um objeto, onde um arquivo de configurações é lido e o atributo `msg` é definido de acordo com o idioma que está dentro do arquivo.

---

O que você pode fazer nesse caso, é realizar a verificação dentro do método `__init__`, dessa forma:

```
class Words():

    def __init__(self, value, g_class, first_meaning = True):

        self.value = value
        self.g_class = g_class
        self.first_meaning = first_meaning

        if value in brecht_dict.keys():
            self.meaning = brecht_dict[value]
```

É possível também você definir através do `__init__` o `meaning` como atributo estático, passando o nome da classe ao invés do `self`. Porém ao fazer isso, ele será "compartilhado" com todos os outros objetos, gerando um outro problema para o seu programa. Exemplo:

```
class Perfil():  
    def __init__(self,nome):
        Perfil.nome = nome

pessoa1 = Perfil('Jean')
print(pessoa1.nome) # Saída: Jean

pessoa2 = Perfil('Larissa')
print(pessoa1.nome) # Saída: Larissa (alterou o nome da primeira pessoa)
```

---

**Utilizando @property:**

Se você quer verificar o valor sempre que quiser chamar o `meaning`, você pode utilizar o `@property`.

De uma forma bem simples de se entender, o `@property` é um [decorador](https://code.tutsplus.com/pt/tutorials/deep-dive-into-python-decorators--cms-29725) e o que ele faz é transformar um método em uma espécie de atributo. Ele é utilizado para restringir o uso de um atributo ou então executar um bloco de código ao chamar, modificar ou deletar um atributo. O seu código ficaria dessa forma:

```
class Words():

    def __init__(self, value, g_class, first_meaning = True):

        self.value = value
        self.g_class = g_class
        self.first_meaning = first_meaning

    @property
    def meaning(self)
        if self.value in brecht_dict.keys():
                return brecht_dict[self.value]
```

Comment: Excelente, Jean!